# Beginner programmer: Password generator

Tags: python, passwords, ascii

As the title says, I am absolutely new to programming. I'm getting horribly stuck unfortunately. I have to make a random password generator using the ASCII table. I am NOT allowed to import string, nor am I allowed to use an alphabet string and select characters from it, I am only allowed to use CHR or ORD functions, lists and other very basic level functions that I have been taught in class. I am encouraged to define my own function.

I got the code to work briefly but it was executing each option 3 times each and therefore going way over the character count of 7-14. So instead I have tried a variable that has three choices which is supposed to execute either an uppercase, lowercase or number depending on what it gets. This is my code so far:

```
for loop in range(10):

    import random

    password = ""
    randLength = random.randint(7, 14)

    lower = random.randint(97, 122)
    upper = random.randint(65, 90)
    number = random.randint(0, 9)

    for n in range(randLength):
        randChoice = random.randint(1, 3)
        if randChoice == 1:
            choice = lower
        elif randChoice == 2:
            choice = upper
        else:
            choice = number
        result = chr(lower) + chr(upper) + str(number)
    password += result

    print(password)
```

As of now my coding is printing one lowercase, one uppercase and one number (in that exact same order every single time), but it won't repeat the process to reach a desired random length of 7-14, nor do I want it to remain in the same 'pattern' every time, it's meant to be random after all.

How would I also modify my code to prevent two identical characters appearing side by side in my output? Please help a newbie! Thanks

Comment: I just tried that and it still does the same thing :-/

Comment: Your indentation is wrong for `password += result`. And your `lower`, `upper`, `number` needs to be moved into the inner for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic way I can think of is this:

```
>>> from random import sample, randint
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from string import ascii_letters, digits
>>> print ''.join(sample(list(chain(ascii_letters, digits)), randint(7, 14)))
qniksOzH0w
```

This will work fine for you and your restrictions:

```
for loop in range(10):
    import random

    password = ""
    randLength = random.randint(7, 14)

    for n in range(randLength):
        lower = random.randint(97, 122)
        upper = random.randint(65, 90)
        number = random.randint(0, 9)
        randChoice = random.randint(1, 3)
        while True:
            if randChoice == 1:
                choice = chr(lower)
            elif randChoice == 2:
                choice = chr(upper)
            else:
                choice = str(number)
            if not choice in password:
                password += choice
                break

    print(password)
```

Output:

```
3UA25yqL
GmdH1dT4M9
6rUUtMe7GkK
G5VSfH4XLP05Q
wbQF2gh29V4sk
yv74xlxL2S2SH
473TUlfh5
N3F5W8j
S5U1K0fcJl4cOE
62R4ZT1k
```

Comment: You're amazing, I can't believe I overlooked such simple mistakes, you've been an awesome help! Is there a way I can make it so that it doesn't present two characters in a row of the same value? For e.g. 22, CC, EE, etc? The characters can be of a different case so Ee, or Dd, but not of the same case.

Comment: Sorry about removing your answer, I learned shortly after posting that I could have potentially gotten in trouble in my class for posting the question online! However, enough time has passed now and the work didn't amount to anything meaningful during my degree so I have re-accepted your answer. Many thanks from all that time ago :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
from random import randint

randLength = randint(7,14)
characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
password = ''
for i in range(randLength):
    password += characters[randint(0, len(characters) - 1)];
print password
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here, but the one you've described is because result is simply the three random characters added together. You're not using the value of 'choice' anywhere:

```
result = chr(lower) + chr(upper) + str(number)
```

Instead of assigning to choice, try adding to result inside your loop:

```
if randChoice == 1:  
    result = result + lower
```

etc

Once you do this, you'll spot the second issue...